# How to create rule in GitHub?

Tags: github

Rule that i want to create is, "If any developer push some piece of code than it should be verify by senior developer before merging in root repository. Once code get verify by the Senior developer than code should get merge in Root repository ".

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is [branch protection](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches).

With branch protections, you can protect the master branch from merging outside of a pull request, and you can require one or more code reviews before a pull request is considered mergeable. Then, delegate code reviewing power to your senior developers, and you'll have a protected master branch.